# Background some quando meus itens do menu estão na horizontal

Tags: css

Tenho o seguinte código HTML:

```
<div id="topo">
    <div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

E o seguinte CSS:

```
#topo {
    background-color: #1a1e27;
    color:#FFFFFF; 
    width:950px;
}
#topo li {
    display:inline;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Quando deixo esse código inteiro, ele perde o background `#1a1e27` mas deixa meu menu na horizontal. Quando tiro todo o `#topo li {}`, ele atribui a cor do background.

O que estou fazendo errado?

Comment: @Bacco Na realidade, o problema pode ser reproduzido somente com o código original postado: http://jsfiddle.net/tZe4L/

Comment: @Rod agora acertei as 2 cores, veja se é isso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Percebi alguns problemas: Como você usou display: inline, o float não é necessário,
e como existe um `<a>`, a cor branca do `<li>` não está fazendo efeito.

Este css soluciona os dois problemas:

```
#topo {
   background-color: #1a1e27;
   width:950px;
}
#topo li {
   display:inline;
   margin-left: 5px;
}
#topo a {
   color:#FFFFFF; 
}
```

Comment: @mgibsonbr agora que eu percebi o float :)

Comment: Boa, isso também funciona. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tZe4L/2/

Comment: é, aquela hora eu estava rascunhando no fiddle que o @mgibsonbr postou, e foi ai que eu percebi o float sobrando :)

Comment: obrigado Bacco, então float, só funciona em elementos em bloco

Comment: @Rod Não, float funciona em qualquer elemento, e elementos flutuados são tratados como blocos.

Answer (score 3):

Quando você flutua os elementos dentro de um *container*, ele se comporta como se estivesse vazio – portanto sem dimensões, e sem background. A solução é colocar `overflow: hidden` no container para "limpar" os floats. Repare também que `float: left` anula o seu `display: inline`. O CSS pode então ficar assim:

```
#topo {
    background-color: #1a1e27;
    color:#FFFFFF; 
    width:950px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#topo li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

<sup>http://jsfiddle.net/tZe4L/1/</sup>

Ou, como sugeriu o Bacco, você pode colocar seus `<li>` inline, sem flutuá-los.